# F#: Xamarin Forms DLL loading error after upgrading FSharp.Core Nuget package

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms

I've just upgraded FSharp.Core to Version 4.1.0 in my Xamarin Forms project. When instantiating a class that uses F# expressions, I get a runtime error.

The exception message is

> Could not load file or assembly
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Astrid.Mobile.Droid/files/.__ override __/en-US/FSharp.Core.resources.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies

and the stack trace is

> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:LoadFrom
>   (string,bool)   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom (System.String
>   assemblyFile) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/f3074d2c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:532
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly
>   (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
>   System.Version version, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x000c5] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/f3074d2c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:511

Worryingly, when I look for FSharp.Core.resources.dll on Google, the scammers have picked it up. All I get is a bunch of websites that promise to fix the problem as long as I download and run their "fix".

Is there a fix or a workaround for this issue that doesn't involve downloading a Trojan horse?

Also, does anyone know what FSharp.Core.resources.dll even is? It looks like Xamarin has mistaken FSharp.Core.dll for a localisable assembly, and tried to load an associated resources project.

**UPDATE**

So deep within mscorlib, there is a class called `ManifestBasedResourceGroveler`, and its `GrovelForResourceSet` method is invoked, via `ResourceManager.GetString()` by various classes in FSharp.Core.dll.

It may not be the actual version of mscorlib that drives Android, but it is clear from the reference source, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/resources/manifestbasedresourcegroveler.cs, that `GrovelForResourceSet` is trying to load the non-existent file FSharp.Core.resources.dll. What is not clear is why it seems to think this file exists, and how I can convince the system that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you using VS 2017?  If not, I'd recommend locking your version to the 4.0.0.1 nuget, especially if trying to get things to work with Xamarin, which is a 'there be dragons' thing to begin with...

Comment: Thanks for this. I reverted to 4.0.0.1, but the problem persisted. It may be the latest version of Xamarin that is causing this.

Comment: I used to see this in fuslogvw but the actual exception I was getting was about strong name validation failure. When I solved the strong name issue, that error went away as well.